# Uninstall a .exe on uninstall setup(.exe) created using Install sheild

Tags: installshield

I created a Windows form setup using install shield.
Is it possible to stop other services (ex: .exe's) in my system  while uninstalling setup created using install shield.

Is this possible while creating setup using Install shield or I want any scripts in my app to stop certain services while uninstalling my setup.

Comment: Most tools that create an MSI setup have support for using the standard Windows Installer functionality of StartServices and StopServices. Your version of InstallShield may do that, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

**Service installation settings** are found in the "**Advanced Settings**" view of each individual component if you have the right version of Installshield - I am not sure what features "light versions" have.

If you don't have an appropriate version of Installshield you can always use a VBScript or similar to stop any service you want.

[image]